# How can I log to App Insights from Azure API Management 'send-request'

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management policy which contains a "send-request":

```
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="response" timeout="5" ignore-error="false">
        <set-url>https://www.bing.com</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
    </send-request>
```

App Insights displays the request to operation, but not the "send-request" URL.

App Insights configuration in API Management:

Sampling: 100%
Verbosity: Verbose
Request Payload: 8192

Query:

```
union
requests,
dependencies
| order by timestamp
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[API Management integrated with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights#what-data-is-added-to-azure-application-insights) logs only the below items:

> - Request telemetry item, for every incoming request (frontend request, frontend response),
> - Dependency telemetry item, for every request forwarded to a backend service (backend request, backend response),
> - Exception telemetry item, for every failed request.

Unfortunately, it does not log API dependency/requests from policy. It would only log exceptions when something fails.

You can post feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management).

Comment: I already contacted the Product group and they told me that they are already working on it.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer - any update on this after 2 years? Did they add this capability?

Comment: @user1102532 It's still not working and I do not have an update from Microsoft